# Android - how to implement color detection using opencv?

Tags: android, opencv, colors, computer-vision, detection

i`m trying to write an application that will detect red objects appearing in a live preview (taken from the camera.
my goal is to provide a gray-scale preview and on top of it to show the red colored objects.

i`v read [this](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/), and was trying to play with the OpenCV-2.3.1 samples but with no avail...

any kind of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)?

Comment: hi Samuel. i gave it a try but couldn't run the code due to so many environmental errors.. the thing is i think opencv has more flexibility and much more support over the web.

Comment: What have you tried, and at what point did it fail? Compiler errors? Running code but no preview? No working color detection?

Comment: i got a message that the device wont be able to run the code due missing native code..

Comment: JavaCV provides a Java interface to the C API of OpenCV. This is why I was asking if you were trying to use JavaCV or instead trying to use OpenCV in some other way.